# Как решить проблему выхода из сна Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, kubuntu

***Всем привет)***

Пользуюсь уже давненько `linux (Ubuntu)`, часто на форумах видел, что много в кого ноутбук засыпает и со сна не выходит! У меня не было такого до последнего времени, но сейчас , когда закрываю крышку - он просто засыпает и когда нажимаю на пробел (или любую другую клавишу ) он просто застывает черным экраном!

Пробывал на нескольких ноутбуках:

- Acer aspire v3-571g
- Lenovo IdeaPad Z510 i5 4200M

*Проблемы - одинаковые!*

Поставил драйвера на `Nvidia` - комп включается/выключается бес проблем, но вот со сна не выходит!

Пробовал несколько дистрибутивов:

1. Ubuntu 16.04
2. Ubuntu 14.04
3. Xbuntu 16.04
4. Kubuntu 16.04
5. Ubuntu Gnome 16.04

Все работают нормально но со сна нигде не выходит!

**В чем может быть проблема ?? Как это можно решить ?**

**Возможно есть linux где нет таких проблем ?**

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# See logind.conf(5) for details

[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
Controllers=blkio cpu cpuacct cpuset devices freezer hugetlb memory perf_event net_cls net_prio
ResetControllers=
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
#HandleSuspendKey=suspend
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
```

Comment: /var/log/pm-powersave.log, /var/log/pm-suspend.log - смотрели?

Comment: А вы под "сном" подразумеваете "режим пониженного энергопотребления, но не полное отключение питания" или "запись состояния на диск и полное отключение питания"?

Comment: @МАН69К, добавил их к вопросу

Comment: Присоединяюсь к вопросу. У меня при переходе в сон экран начинает истерически мигать и жёсткий диск издаёт странные звуки, после чего приходится перезагружаться. Тоже пробовал на различных дистрибутивах, пробовал файл подкачки увеличивать, ничего не помогает. Видимо какие-то драйвера несовместимы.

Comment: В логах кстати появляется такое вот сообщение: "ata3: SRST failed (errno=-16)"